# onPress to delete task problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my onPress and the props.

I have a Task component that is called in a homeScreen component that displays a list with array.map.

I want to add a delete function to the press of the "delete" task

Sequence of the problem:

When I click on my "create task" button, it shows me my modal with two textinput fields: task name and description.

When I create a task, it goes well in the array tasks. But when I retype in the field: the task is deleted. I have the impression that the deleteItem function is called when a change is made ..

the delete function is called. I thought it was from the onPress () but I feel like who launches it every time ...

```
const Task =(props) =>{
    return (
      <View style={styles.task}>
        <View style={{ flex:1,flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:'space-between',marginTop:15,}}>
          <Text style={styles.TextTasks }> {props.text}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.deleteitem}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>Supprimer</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
      </View>
        );
  }
const Buttons = (props)=>{
  return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.SectionStyleAdd}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.press}  style={{flexDirection:"row",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",width:200}} >
        <Image source={require('./Icon/add.png')} style={styles.ImageStyle} />
            <Text> Créer une tâche</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
        </View>
  )
}
export default function HommeScreen(props) {
    const [isFocused, setisFocused] = useState(false);
  const [tasks, settasks] = useState([]);
    const [taskName,settaskName] = useState("");
    const [taskDescription, settaskDescription] = useState("");
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

    const   deleteItem = (index) => {
        console.log("salut")
        const tmp= tasks.splice(index,1)
        console.log(tmp)
    };
    const addItem = event => 
        {
        settasks([
            ...tasks,
            {
                id: tasks.length,
                name: taskName,
                description:taskDescription,
            }
        ]);
        settaskName("");
        settaskDescription("");
        console.log(tasks)
    };
    
    const handlefocus = (event) =>{
        setisFocused({isFocused:true})
        if(props.onFocus){
            props.onFocus(event);
    }
}
    const handlebutton=()=>{
        setShowModal(!showModal);
}
  return (
<View style={{ flex:1 }}>
    <Modal 
        onBackButtonPress={() =>handlebutton()}
        isVisible={showModal}
        transparent={true}
  >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor:"white",height:400,marginTop:300,padding:40,borderRadius:50}}>
            <TextInput   
                style={{height: 40,width:300}}  
                selectionColor={isFocused ? BLUE : LIGHT_GREY} 
                underlineColorAndroid={"#D3D3D3"} 
                placeholder="Nom tâches:" 
                value={taskName}
                onChangeText={tasks => settaskName(tasks)} >
            </TextInput >

            <TextInput   
            style={{height: 40,width:300}}
            value={taskDescription}
            selectionColor={isFocused ? BLUE : LIGHT_GREY} 
            underlineColorAndroid={"#D3D3D3"} 
            placeholder="Description de la tâches:" 
            onChangeText= {taskDescription => settaskDescription(taskDescription)} 
            >
            </TextInput >
            <TouchableOpacity style={{height:30,width:100,borderColor:BLUE,borderWidth:2,borderRadius:50,justifyContent:"center"}}
                onPress={()=>addItem()}>
                <Text> Créer la tâche</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </Modal>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop:50}}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:"row"  }}>
        <SearchBar/>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text style={ styles.title }> Tâche à faire:</Text>
      </View>
            {tasks.length ? (
        <ScrollView>
          <View>
            {tasks.map((element,index) => {
                            console.log("element: "+element.name,index)
              return <Tasks  deleteitem={deleteItem(index)} key={element.id} text={element.name}  />;
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        ) : (
          <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1 }}>
            <Text>Aucune Tâches</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={{ marginTop:15 }}>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={{ position:"absolute",bottom:0,right:0,marginBottom:30,marginRight:25}}>
        <Buttons press={handlebutton}></Buttons>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>

</View>
    
  );
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your scrollview where you are mapping tasks, try this

```
<ScrollView>
          <View>
            {tasks.map((element,index) => {
              console.log("element: "+element.name,index)
              return <Tasks  deleteitem={()=>deleteItem(index)} key={element.id} text={element.name}  />;    //changed deleteitem
            })}
          </View>
</ScrollView>
```